# Parsing date string with moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I am trying to parse a date string with moment. To help me see what is going on I have these two log statements

```
console.log('Before moment parse',deadline)
console.log('After moment parse:',moment(deadline).format('MMMM Mo YYYY HH:mm'))
```

which prints

```
Before moment parse 2222-12-12T12:12:00Z
After moment parse: December 12th 2222 13:12
```

Why does moment add an hour to my date string?

Comment: are you in UTC+1 timezone?

Comment: What timezone are you in? The `Z` at the end of the first log line indicates Zulu-time which is basically UTC.

Comment: yes @JaromandaX

Comment: well, there's your answer `December 12th 2222 13:12` in your timezone is exactly the same time as `2222-12-12T12:12:00Z` ... therefore, moment is not adding anything at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MomentJS is adding hours because you are telling it to add the hours, with `HH:mm`

use

```
console.log('After moment parse:',moment(deadline).format('MMMM Mo YYYY'))
```

Comment: Oh sorry, guess I wasn't clear enough. I mean it increments my hours by + 1 when I parse the string for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Moment parses and displays in local time, by default. You should parse date in UTC before you format it:

```
moment('2222-12-12T12:12:00Z').utc().format('MMMM Mo YYYY HH:mm')
```